# How to query elasticsearch from kibana using regex with - in it?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to query Elasticsearch where source is as follows:

`source => /home/user/logs/serviceA.inst-app3.test.log.INFO.20180204-084131.21231`

I want to filter all messages where source is `serviceA.*INFO*`. However, Kibana returns empty list. For queries like `serviceA.*` or `serviceA*` queries, Kibana returns the result where `serviceA.inst` is highlighted. My suspicion is minus sign in the file name is causing the issue.

How to query Elasticsearch from Kibana with regex which has minus sign (-) in it?

Comment: I think the issue is that your source field is analyzed an so the string is separated on the minus sign. Maybe try filtering source.keyword for serviceA.*INFO*?

Comment: Thanks! It worked.